# How to reuse the same test multiple times in RSPEC

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

In one of my rspec test files, I need to run the following (otherwise identical) test in several different contexts:

```
describe "view the event with request" do
  before {
    click_link("Swimming lessons")
  }

  it { should have_content "Party Supplies"}

  describe "view the contribute form" do
    before {
      click_button("Party Supplies")
    }

    it {
      within("#bodyPopover") {
        should have_content('cupcakes')
        should have_content('napkins')
      }
    }


  end

end
```

I'd like to be able to put all this in a method (say `view_the_event_and_contribute_form`) and just use that method in several places in the rest of the test. Can that be accomplished? I tried defining a method which simply had that code, but it didn't recognize `describe` from within that method.

What's the best way to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can turn those tests into a [shared_example](https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-core/v/3-2/docs/example-groups/shared-examples):

```
shared_example "event with request" do
  before { click_link("Swimming lessons") }

  it { should have_content "Party Supplies"}

  describe "view the contribute form" do
    before { click_button("Party Supplies") }

    specify {
      within("#bodyPopover") {
        should have_content('cupcakes')
        should have_content('napkins')
      }
    }
  end
end
```

From other tests use `it_behaves_like` to run the shared examples:

```
describe 'Some other awesome tests' do
  it_behaves_like "event with request"
end
```

Comment: Sorry about the delay in response here. This does the trick except it needed (at least in my case) to be `shared_examples` (plural). I'm going to edit and mark as solved. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You almost had it. Just remove the `describe`, `before` and `it` blocks and move that code within a plain method.